# Euclid's algorithm using until

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell, just started now learning about folds and what not, in college, first year.

One of the problems I'm facing now is to define Euclid's algorithm using the `until` function.

Here's the Euclid's recursive definition (EDIT: just to show how euclid works, I'm trying to define euclid's without the recursive. Just using until):

```
gcd a b = if b == 0 then a else gcd b (a `mod` b)
```

Here's what i have using until:

```
gcd a b = until (==0) (mod a ) b
```

Obviously this doesn't make any sense since it's always going to return `0`, as that is my stopping point instead of printing the value of a when `b == 0`. I can't for the life of me though figure out how to get the value of `a`.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the Euclid's algorithm says is this: for `(a, b)`, computing `(b, mod a b)` until (the new) `b` equals zero. This can be translated directly to an implementation using `until` like this:

```
myGcd a b = until (\(x, y) -> y == 0) (\(x, y) -> (y, x `mod` y)) (a, b)
```

Comment: some other people, including myself, were not giving out the final answer because the OP is supposed to learn not get working solutions...

Comment: @ErikAllik That implementation is a directly translation of the explanation before it, even if I did not offer it, the asker should be able to figure it out by himself. Anyway, I hope he did learn how to do it by himself through my explanation and example.

Answer (score 4):

### Hints:

Now

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

so we need a function that we can apply repeatedly until a condition holds, but we have two numbers `a` and `b`, so how can we do that?

The solution is to make the two numbers into one value, `(a,b)`, so think of `gcd` this way:

```
uncurriedGCD (a,b) = if b == 0 then (a,a) else uncurriedGCD (b,a `mod` b)
```

Now you can make two functions, `next` &  `check` and use them with `until`.

### Helpers for `until`:

```
next (a,b) = (b,a `mod` b)
check (a,b) = b == 0
```

This means that we now could have written `uncurriedGCD` using `until`.

### Answer:

For example:

```
ghci> until check next (6,4)
(2,0)
ghci> until check next (12,18)
(6,0)
```

So we can define:

```
gcd a b = c where (c,_) = until check next (a,b)
```

giving:

```
ghci> gcd 20 44
4
ghci> gcd 60 108
12
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having some trouble understanding your answer..You're saying i cant write the function without the recursive ? I'm trying to define Euclid's using only until..The recursive's there for the people who don't know how euclid works.

Comment: He's saying you need to carry 2 values all along when using `until` not just one. Analogously to what's happening in the recursive version.